# How to write a doctoral thesis?

Tags: creative-writing, technical-writing, academic-writing

A few days ago I attended a seminar titled "How to write your doctoral thesis?". I was not able to follow all the points during the seminar. However, the most remarkable ones are easily conceivable.

My question to you is to list a number of clear points about writing doctoral thesis. For example: things we must write in the introduction. Things we must avoid in the conclusion. Etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you're asking which style to adopt (for example active/passive voice, use of tenses) that might be an interesting question - but be careful to avoid it being a duplicate. If you're asking for details of a specific course, contacting the course provider might be a better solution. Can you edit your post to make it more specific?

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere I just edit the question

Comment: I've had a go at an answer to the question within the parameters of this site. If there's something else you were asking that fits the site guidelines, it might be worth considering a further edit. Out of curiosity, what were some of the remarkable / easily conceivable points?

Answer (score 1):

This still seems a fairly broad question, so I'll assume you're already aware of the things to do and things not to do in academia and will concentrate on a general point of writing style based on the defining factor of a doctoral thesis - that you are making an original contribution to knowledge in your field of study.

The original information is the important factor. You will want to make sure this is mentioned in the introduction and conclusion. In choosing your writing style, concentrate on objectivity and the importance of the new information - finding your own voice in expressing details is fine, but if we consider the search for this information to be a story, you're the narrator not the protagonist.

I'm not going to write a list of points, as these are readily available using your question heading in an available search engine. For example :

http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/~jw/thesis.html

https://www.theguardian.com/higher-education-network/blog/2014/aug/27/finishing-phd-thesis-top-tips-experts-advice

and, from the perspective of someone assessing theses :

https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/how-not-to-write-a-phd-thesis/410208.article